# How can I use NuGet with SSDT?

Tags: nuget, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on an Integration Services project.
One of the data sources I use calls for a package to be installed from NuGet.

I tried to go to "Tools > NuGet Package Manager",
but it is not available in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).

Next I tried to install NuGet by downloading it from the nuget.org website,
but I got the following error:

> VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

How can I use NuGet with SSDT?

Comment: Nuget support is in preview since may 2023. Those who are looking for the same, see this  (contains links to MS docs) https://stackoverflow.com/a/76220165/5921826

Answer (score 3):

The SSIS project type doesn't support Nuget.

It is possible to add a nuget reference to the csproj associated with a script task, but this may cause further discomfort at deployment time.

You can download nuget.exe by itself from nuget.org and install packages from the command line, but given the "special" requirements for installing external dlls used by SSIS it might be as easy to find a non-nuget source for the component you need.

Comment: As an example... I need to use ODP.Net to connect to Oracle within Azure SSIS. It comes as a nuget package which can't be added in SSDT (nor I assume in the actual SSIS runtime) . You need to find the older ZIP version and install it manually.

Comment: Well, a nuget package is just a zip file really, you could extract the dll you need and add it manually.