# How to fix NuGet WinSCP.NET in SSIS Script Task?

Tags: c#, ssis, winscp-net

I'm trying to use the WinSCP.NET NuGet to upload some files to an SFTP through a Script Task component in SSIS. While writing the code everything went fine, but if after attempting to build, the WinSCP.NET dll seems to not be picked up breaking all of the references.

I've tried adding WinSCP path to my PATH variable (user). I've tried to add the local version of the WinSCPNET.dll to the GAC. I've tried to reinstall the package through NuGet. I've even tried to change the framework versions.

This is a problem I've had before with the WinSCP.NET DLL. Last time I ended up using a workaround by interfacing with the command line through C#. But I would like to use the DLL, as it's a much simpler implementation.

The code is basically the boilerplate from WinSCP, with some minor changes:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WinSCP;
#endregion

namespace ST_a1d3d6e0b5d54338bce6c79882c303c6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            // User::FileName,$Package::SFTP_HostName,$Package::SFTP_Password,$Package::SFTP_PortNumber,$Package::SFTP_UserName
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::SFTP_HostName"].Value,
                UserName = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::SFTP_Password"].Value,
                SshHostKeyFingerprint = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::SFTP_Fingerprint"].Value,
                Password = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::SFTP_Password"].GetSensitiveValue(),
                PortNumber = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::SFTP_PortNumber"].Value,
            };

            try
            {
                using (Session session = new Session())
                {
                    // As WinSCP .NET assembly has to be stored in GAC to be used with SSIS,
                    // you need to set path to WinSCP.exe explicitly,
                    // if using non-default location.
                    session.ExecutablePath = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::WinSCP_Path"].Value;

                    // Connect
                    session.Open(sessionOptions);

                    // Upload files
                    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                    TransferOperationResult transferOperationResult = session.PutFiles(
                        (string)Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value, (string) Dts.Variables["$Package::SFTP_RemoteFileName"].Value, 
                        true, transferOptions);

                    // Throw on any error
                    transferOperationResult.Check();

                    // Print results
                    bool fireAgain = false;
                    foreach (TransferEventArgs transferEvent in transferOperationResult.Transfers)
                    {
                        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, null,
                            string.Format("Upload of {0} succeeded", transferEvent.FileName),
                            null, 0, ref fireAgain);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, null,
                    string.Format("Error when using WinSCP to upload files: {0}", e),
                    null, 0);

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of VSTA Project references]

This should compile as is and allow me to run the SSIS, to upload the file. Instead the references break and I receive a lot of missing reference errors:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WinSCP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error: This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\WinSCP.5.15.0\build\WinSCP.targets.

Answer (score 3):

I can indeed reproduce your problem, when I use [WinSCP NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSCP/). It looks like a problem between the NuGet package manager and SQL Server Data Tools. The file the error refers to actually does exist (in a path relative to the script task `.csproj` file).

Actually, it looks like it's not even recommended to use NuGet in SSIS. You should rather register the assembly to GAC:

- [How can I use NuGet with SSDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40977714/850848)
- [Creating a reference to a custom assembly from an SSIS Script Task - vb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48167744/850848)
- [SSIS Script Task cant find reference to assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37681631/850848)

---

And indeed, if I follow the [WinSCP instructions for using the assembly from SSIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis) (using the GAC), it works just fine.

- Make sure you have uninstalled the NuGet package.
- [Install `WinSCPnet.dll` to GAC](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#gac) or [subscribe `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis#subscribe).
- And add `WinSCPnet.dll` to your script task project.